# Can you give me idea on how to code this program using array and for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I was supposed to make a program using for loop and arrays now the output program will need to show something like this

```
0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-1
```

Notice that the `0` is adding every after the `1`'s show so far im stuck with this code can you help me please...

```
int[] binary = new int[150];
int b = 0;
int x = 3;
for(int a = 0; a < binary.length; a=a+2) {
  box[a] =1;
}

for(int i =0; i < binary.length; i++){ 
  for(b = 0; b < binary.length; b = b+x){
    if(box[b] == 1) {
      box[b] =0;  // this condition changes the value of  1 to 0 if the binary is already "1".
    }
    else {
      box[b] =1; // if the value of the binary is 0 it changes it to 1.
    }
  }
  x++; // Putting this changes the value of the x making x=4 so that the next time the for loop runs it adds the int b to 4..(NOT SURE IF THIS IS RIGHT THOUGH)
}

for(int c =0; c < binary.length; c++) {
  System.out.print(binary[c]); // "this should print the output "
}
```

My problem is making it show something like this

```
01001000100001000001
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: You really need to clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @xgeorgekx 10110111 something like this its up to 150 so its too long if wrote all down

Comment: @IvanLorenzo I have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing multiple variable names, since you assign the values to box you should probably remove `binary` - so something like,

```
int[] box = new int[150];
int b = 0;
int x = 3;
for (int a = 0; a < box.length; a = a + 2) {
    box[a] = 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    for (b = 0; b < box.length; b = b + x) {
        if (box[b] == 1) {
            box[b] = 0;
        } else {
            box[b] = 1;
        }
    }
    x++;
}

for (int c = 0; c < box.length; c++) {
    System.out.print(box[c]); // "this should print the output "
}
```

Output is

```
101101111011111101111111101111111111011111111111101111111111111101111111111111111011111111111111111101111111111111111111101111111111111111111111011111
```

Comment: right before the x++; do you think i should add.right at the top of it b=0 just to reset the value of "b" back to 0.?

Comment: @IvanLorenzo I don't think so, the next loop iteration will do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand what you want. From your post I only understand that your goal is to have an output composed of 0 and 1 only and starting with a 0 immediately followed by a 1. The number of zeros following a 1 is successively increased by 1 : so you have after that 2 zeros followed by a 1 and then 3 zeros followed by a 1, 4 zeros followed by a 1 and so one : 0-1-00-1-000-1-0000-1.

Am I right ?

If that is what you want,  try something like that :

```
    int num_zero = 1;
    int cptr = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[20];

    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){


        if(cptr == num_zero){

            arr[j] = 1;
            num_zero = 1+ cptr;
            cptr = 0;


        }else{

            arr[j] = 0;
            ++cptr;

        }
    }
```

Here is the output :

```
01001000100001000001
```

Comment: Actually cptr is used to store the number of zeros added just after a 1. When the right number, stored in num_zero, is reached, you enter in the if statement, add a 1 and reset cptr.

Comment: incrementing the value of the cptr in the else condition is that what the ++cptr means?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] binary = new int[150];
int onesNextIndex = 1;
int onesGap = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < binary.length; i++){
    if(i == onesNextIndex){
        binary[i] = 1;
        onesNextIndex += onesGap + 1;
        onesGap++;

    }else{
        binary[i] = 0;
    }   
}
```

You can test it with:

```
for(int x : binary){
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

it will print: `0100100010000100000100000010000000100000000..... etc`

if you want it the other way around then :

```
int[] binary = new int[150];
int zerosNextIndex = 1;
int zerosGap = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < binary.length; i++){
    if(i == zerosNextIndex){
        binary[i] = 0;
        zerosNextIndex += zerosGap + 1;
        onesGap++;

    }else{
        binary[i] = 1;
    }

}
```

this will print: `101101110111101111101111110111111101111111101111.......etc`

Hope this helps